# javax/inject/Inject.class in lib/javax.inject-1.jar is hidden by lib/javax.inject-2.5.0-b42.jar on onejar executable

Tags: maven, jar, executable-jar, onejar

I am attempting to create an atomic executable jar (i.e. no dependencies outside of the jar).

To do this I have added a com.jolira:onejar-maven-plugin in my pom.xml.  This seems to do the job, but when I execute the jar I get the warnings:
    JarClassLoader: Warning: Null manifest from input stream associated with: lib/javax.inject-1.jar
    JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/inject/Inject.class in lib/javax.inject-1.jar is hidden by lib/javax.inject-2.5.0-b42.jar (with different bytecode)
    JarClassLoader: Warning: javax/inject/Named.class in lib/javax.inject-1.jar is hidden by lib/javax.inject-2.5.0-b42.jar (with different bytecode)

It seems that my dependencies are pulling in both javax.inject-1.jar and javax.inject-2.5.0-b42.jar.  To verify this I checked and both have/are being downloaded from the repository.  I certainly don't have both listed in the dependencies, so there must be some implied dependency AFAICS.

Anyone know if there is a way to exclude just one jar from a maven dependency, or alternately to prevent onejar-maven-plugin from including it in the executable jar?

Is there a better way to create an atomic (or some call them fat) jar where the java loader can actually load from an embedded jar.  I've tried all day with various different recipes and onejar was the only one that actually got the loaded to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting this here for future.
I solved the problem in this way:
(It's for project's dependency which has javax.inject in its own dependencies)

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't seem to help.  Ass this to the onejar-maven-plugin?

Comment: It's for project's dependency which has javax.inject in its own dependencies

Answer (score 1):

After some playing I found Alex's solution to be correct, just that I had put the exclude in the wrong place.  The solution is to put it here:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
  <version>2.26</version>
  <exclusions> <!--  exclude exclude javax.inject-1.jar -->
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```