# "NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Provider" even with javax.inject dependency included

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, grizzly

After upgrading some Glassfish/Grizzly dependencies (in order to be compatible with the latest version of Azure's SDK IOT device client), I started getting an error because com.google.common.EventBus no longer existed. Adding the dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

fixed that, and it was able to run locally in IntelliJ. However, when I deployed the .deb file that was compiled to a Raspberry Pi, it started producing the error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Provider
>           at com.google.inject.internal.MoreTypes.canonicalizeForKey(MoreTypes.jav
>   a:81)
>           at com.google.inject.Key.(Key.java:119)
>           at com.google.inject.Key.get(Key.java:212)
>           at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.bind(Elements.java:262
>   )
>           at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$RootModule.configure(InjectorShell.java:276)
>           at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
>           at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
>           at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
>           at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
>           at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
>           at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
>           at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
>           at com.infusion.empm.Main.main(Main.java:32) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.inject.Provider
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)

I read in a number of places that adding the dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

is supposed to fix that (I already had the guice & javax-servlet-api dependencies referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822568/noclassdeffounderror-javax-inject-provider-and-classnotfoundexception-javax-in)), but it had no effect. When I do so, the result is two javax.inject jars (the other one being generated would seem to explain why I didn't need to explicitly add version 1 to get it to run locally):

> javax.inject-2.5.0-b42.jar
>
> javax.inject-1.jar

[Someone else here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47802885/javax-inject-inject-class-in-lib-javax-inject-1-jar-is-hidden-by-lib-javax-injec) used exclusions when they had those two jars, but even when I change my hk2 dependency accordingly, both jars are still present. I've also heard that adding javax.ws.rs-api is supposed to help, but that was already there. The imports in the Java code refer directly to com.google.inject.Provider, so I don't think there's any need to call guicify to convert a JSR-330 provider to a Guice one. Replacing every "com.google.inject" import in the local code with "java.inject" results in the same exact behavior, so it must be a dependency referencing google's code, which is in turn failing to find javax.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the cause was a script on the Pi which hardcoded the jars in the classpath.